# Map Only Mapreduce Text Output

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am writing a mapreduce job. And it is a map only job. My output key contains two elements and the value contains one element. From a table perspective, I want the output to be three columns, and each line is a new record. And it shall be delimited by some special character if possible.

However, I have a hard time implementing it in Java.

My mapper now looks like this:

```
public class <classname> extends Mapper<AvroKey<<schema.class>>, NullWritable, Map<String, String>, Text>{
    public void map(AvroKey<<schema.class>> key, NullWritable value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        CharSequence content = key.datum().getContent();
        Parser dp = new Parser(content);
        dp.parse();
        for (Part part : dp.getResults()) {
            try {
                Map<String, String> myKey = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
                Text myValue = new Text();
                myKey.put(part.getKey1(), part.getKey2());
                myValue = new Text(part.getValue);
                context.write(myKey, myValue);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my job configuration:

```
    ..
    Job job = new Job(conf);
    job.setJarByClass(<classname>.class);
    job.setJobName("Parser");
    String myPath = "mypath";
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(myPath
            + "input.avro"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(myPath + args[0]));
    job.setInputFormatClass(AvroKeyInputFormat.class);
    AvroJob.setInputKeySchema(job, <schemaclass>.getClassSchema());
    job.setMapperClass(<classname>Mapper.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Map.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    return (job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

And now my output looks like this:

```
{key11=key12} text1
{key21=key22} text2
{key31=key32} text3
{key41=key42} text4
```

What do I need to do to make the output looks like:

```
key11|key12|text1
key21|key22|text2
key31|key32|text3
key41|key42|text4
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a Map only job, why not write the output as :

```
context.write(myKey,  NullWritable.get());
```

With the key as concatenation of the 2 keys and the value separated by |.

Comment: NullWritable is a Singleton. You can't create new instance of it. Instead use NullWritable.get().

Answer (score 1):

You can use NullWritable as a key and Text as a value. In Text you can put three elements separated by any delimiter you like.